# Why ASP.NET Core adds claims twice into User.Claims property?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver3, coreclr

I have asp.net core application and the application is using OpenIdConnect authentication using IdentityServer3. When the user is authenticated successfully the application receives proper claims from identity server. I can debug the line `TokenValidatedContext.Ticket.Principal.Claims` in `OnTokenValidatd` and make sure application receives all the claims.

Code Snippet

```
    var connectOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            Authority = authority,
            ClientId = clientId,
            ResponseType = IdentityConstant.IdTokenClaim,
            AuthenticationScheme = IdentityConstant.OpenIdAuthenticationScheme,
            SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postlogoutRedirectUri,
            CallbackPath = IdentityConstant.CallbackPath,
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    var claims = context.Ticket.Principal.Claims;
                    await Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };
```

below is the quick watch of `TokenValidatedContext.Ticket.Principal.Claims` in `OnTokenValidated` handler

[image]

However, after successful authentication when I debug `User.Cliams` in Home controller, I see all the claims are added twice.
Below is the quick watch of `User.Claims` in Home controller

[image]

Why the claims are getting added twice in User.Claims?

Comment: i can't tell how you're seeing that the claims are duplicated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you set openidconnect's `AutomaticAuthenticate` to true. If you look user identities you will see there are two identities(One for cookie other for openidconnect authentication). Since `User.Claims` are sum of these identity claims, you see claims twice. So, removing `AutomaticAuthenticate = true,` from openidconnect options solves the problem.

Comment: I removed `AutomaticAuthenticate = true` from OpenIdConnectOptions and left it for CookieAuthentication.. It worked!!!